# RxJava2 debounce function not working properly in RecyclerView - Android

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I am trying to create a Custom ImageButton which will accumulate clicks and fire an event when user stops clicking the button for 1 second.

I used debounce function for accomplishing this.

The custom ImageButton:

```
public class MBImageButton extends ImageButton {

    private AtomicInteger mCounter;
    private Disposable mDisposable;
    private Observable<Object> observable;
    private OnAccumulatedRequestsRead mOnAccumulatedRequestsRead;
    private OnEverClickListener mOnEverClickListener;
    private int emitEveryMilli = 1000; // every 1 second by default
    private boolean shouldDisposeOnDetachFromWindow = true;

    public MBImageButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MBImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MBImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void setAccumulatedClickListeners(OnEverClickListener onEverClickListener,
                                             OnAccumulatedRequestsRead onAccumulatedRequestsRead) {
        setOnAccumulatedRequestsRead(onAccumulatedRequestsRead);
        setOnEverClickListener(onEverClickListener);
        initClickObservable();
        subscribe();
    }

    private void initClickObservable() {
        observable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
            emitter.setCancellable(() -> setOnClickListener(null));
            try {
                setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    try {
                        final int currentCount = mCounter.incrementAndGet();
                        Timber.d("Clicked: " + currentCount);
                        if (mOnEverClickListener != null) {
                            mOnEverClickListener.onEveryClickListener(currentCount);
                        }
                        emitter.onNext(new Object());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        emitter.onError(e);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        }).doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mDisposable = disposable)
                               .debounce(emitEveryMilli, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private void subscribe() {
        observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(o -> {
                    try {
                        final int count = mCounter.get();
                        if(count==0) return;
                        mCounter.set(0);
                        Timber.d("Accumulated Clicks: " + count);
                        if (mOnAccumulatedRequestsRead != null) {
                            mOnAccumulatedRequestsRead.onAccumulatedRequestsReady(count);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Timber.e(e);
                    }
                }, Timber::e);
    }

    private void init() {
        mCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    public void disposeAccumulatedClickListeners() {
        if (mDisposable != null) {
            mDisposable.dispose();
        }
    }

    public void shouldDisposeOnDetachFromWindow(boolean shouldDisposeOnDetachFromWindow) {
        this.shouldDisposeOnDetachFromWindow = shouldDisposeOnDetachFromWindow;
    }

    public void setEmitEveryMilliseconds(int emitEveryMilli) {
        this.emitEveryMilli = emitEveryMilli;
        initClickObservable();
        subscribe();
    }

    private void setOnEverClickListener(OnEverClickListener onEverClickListener) {
        mOnEverClickListener = onEverClickListener;
    }

    private void setOnAccumulatedRequestsRead(OnAccumulatedRequestsRead onAccumulatedRequestsRead) {
        mOnAccumulatedRequestsRead = onAccumulatedRequestsRead;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (shouldDisposeOnDetachFromWindow) {
            if (mDisposable != null) {
                mDisposable.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OnAccumulatedRequestsRead {
        void onAccumulatedRequestsReady(int count);
    }

    public interface OnEverClickListener {
        void onEveryClickListener(int currentCount);
    }
}
```

The function that setup this imageButton for debouncing is:

```
setAccumulatedClickListeners(OnEverClickListener, OnAccumulatedRequestsRead)
```

When I setup this view out of `RecyclerView`, everything works correctly,

the result looks like this when I click 9 times sequentially:

```
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 2
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 3
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 4
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 5
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 6
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 7
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 8
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 9
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 9
```

When I add this custom ImageButton to RecyclerView ViewHolder the result is not correct for same number of clicks:

```
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 2
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 3
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 2
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 4
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 4
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 2
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 2
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 2
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 0
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 1
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 0
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 0
```

this is another result for again 9 sequential clicks:

```
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 2
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 3
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 2
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 4
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 3
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 4
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 3
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 1
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 0
D/MBImageButton: Clicked: 1
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 1
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 0
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 0
D/MBImageButton: Accumulated Clicks: 0
```

In both times I clicked with the same interval time, But when this button added to RecyclerView it gives strange result.

**What can be the problem ?**

***Update:***

My Adapter simplified implementation:

```
public class ProductRVAdapter extends BaseProductRVAdapter<ProductRVAdapter.ProductVH> {

    private ProductAdapterListener mProductAdapterListener;

    public ProductRVAdapter(List<Product> productList, ProductAdapterListener productAdapterListener) {
        super(productList);
        mProductAdapterListener = productAdapterListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false);
        return new ProductVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductVH holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(productList.get(position), position);

        holder.ib_decrease.setAccumulatedClickListeners(currentCount -> onProductAdapterDecreaseClicked.onClick(holder.ib_decrease),
                count -> {
                    if (mProductAdapterListener != null) {
                        mProductAdapterListener.onProductAdapterProductChangeToWSListener(productList.get(position), position, -count);
                    }
                });

        holder.ib_add.setAccumulatedClickListeners(currentCount -> onProductAdapterAddToCartClicked.onClick(holder.ib_add),
                count -> {
                    if (mProductAdapterListener != null) {
                        mProductAdapterListener.onProductAdapterProductChangeToWSListener(productList.get(position), position, count);
                    }
                });
    }

    public interface ProductAdapterListener {

        void onProductAdapterAddToCartClicked(Product product, int position);

        void onProductAdapterProductChangeToWSListener(Product product, int position, int amountChanged);

        void onProductAdapterDecreaseClicked(Product product, int position);
    }

    public static class ProductVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.iv_productImage)
        ImageView iv_producImage;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_productName)
        TextView tv_productName;
        @BindView(R.id.tv_prodAmount)
        MBTextView tv_prodAmount;

        @BindView(R.id.ib_decrease)
        MBImageButton ib_decrease;
        @BindView(R.id.ib_add)
        MBImageButton ib_add;

        ProductVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }


        public void bind(Product product, int position) {
            tv_productName.setText(product.getName());
            tv_prodAmount.setText(product.getAmount());

            ImageLoader.loadImage(iv_producImage.getContext(), iv_producImage, product.getImg(), R.drawable.ic_category_item);

            ib_decrease.setTag(position);
            ib_add.setTag(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your adapter implementation?

Comment: @azizbekian I have added the adapter implementation

Comment: I cannot see `getItemCount()` implementation, which presumably is in `BaseProductRVAdapter`. How many items do you have?

Comment: You are calling `setAccumulatedClickListeners()` which subscribes to the observable for each item in the list. E.g. you have 10 items in recyclerview, you'd subscribe 10 times to the observable when the recyclerview lays those item. That's not the functionality you desire to have, right?

Comment: It is like this: `public int getItemCount() { return productList == null ? 0 : productList.size(); }` @azizbekian

Comment: In the items there are Add, Remove buttons for each item, so user will click add 10 times, after he stops clicking, i will send 1 request to webservice with 10 items added. So for each item there is 2 subscribes, for add and remove @azizbekian

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136722/discussion-between-mbh-and-azizbekian).

Comment: Publish project where it easy to reproduce problem, because I can not reproduce it in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution

The main problem is when I scroll in the `RecyclerView Adapter`, the vies get detached from window and the function `onDetachedFromWindow` gets called, in that function i `unsubscribe (dispose)` from the observable.

The solutions  tried:

**1. I added attachFunction**

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    if (shouldDisposeOnDetachFromWindow) {
        if (mDisposable != null) {
            if (mDisposable.isDisposed()) {
                initClickObservable();
                subscribe();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Removed the notifyItemChanged(position) calls**

Usually i update the view after some modification using `notifyItemChange()`. Now i update the view directly by setText or similar functions.

It works properly now.